# How to draw a flower using Python turtle

Tags: python, pycharm, turtle-graphics

I am practicing my Python skills. I am curious about how do I draw this flower using turtles and functions, without using `turtle.circle(radius)`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYUsz.png

Moreover, I have made a polygon spiral like this:

```
import turtle
import math


def draw_polygons():
    """"Make t draws a polygon of side sd and length l"""
    sd = 20
    area = 50000
    while sd >= 3:
        side_length = math.sqrt(area / sd * 4 * math.atan(math.pi / sd))
        for i in range(sd):
            for a_color in ["red", "yellow", "blue", "brown", "pink", "green", "black", "orange", "purple"]:
                rest.fillcolor(a_color)
            rest.begin_fill()
            rest.forward(side_length)
            rest.left(360/sd)
            print("side length =", side_length)
        rest.penup()
        rest.forward(side_length / 2)
        rest.pendown()
        rest.right(30)
        sd -= 1

rest = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()


draw_polygons()

wn.exitonclick()
```

I would like to fill every polygon with a different color, what steps did I do wrong? Or what steps should I do next?

The sample polygon spiral looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U9uD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask about two different programs, let's address the second first.  Besides your color issue, your loop logic isn't correct with the `begin_fill()` inside instead of outside the inner loop.  So let's rework that program:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import math

COLORS = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "brown", "pink", "green", "black", "orange", "purple"]

def draw_polygons(sides, area):
    """ Draws a polygon with 'sides' sides and area 'area' """

    for i, sd in enumerate(range(sides, 2, -1)):
        side_length = math.sqrt(area / sd * 4 * math.atan(math.pi / sd))
        # print("side length =", side_length)

        a_color = COLORS[i % len(COLORS)]
        rest.fillcolor(a_color)

        rest.pendown()
        rest.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(sd):
            rest.forward(side_length)
            rest.left(360 / sd)

        rest.end_fill()
        rest.penup()

        rest.forward(side_length / 2)
        rest.right(30)

wn = Screen()

rest = Turtle()
rest.speed('fastest')

draw_polygons(20, 40_000)

rest.hideturtle()

wn.exitonclick()
```

[image]

To return to your original problem, one approach is to lay down each color of rectangle before doing the next color of rectangle.  Here's a rework of your code to draw just the flower petal portion of the image since I assume that's what you're asking about.  I just eyeballed some of the distances and angles below, you'll need to do the math to get them right:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import math

COLORS = ["green", "orange", "red", "yellow"]

def draw_polygons(area):
    """ Draws a circle using rectangles with area 'area' """

    side_length = math.sqrt(area * math.atan(math.pi / 4))

    for a_color in COLORS:

        for _ in range(12):

            rest.fillcolor(a_color)

            rest.forward(3 * side_length / 10)
            rest.right(15)

            rest.left(112)  # I eyeballed this angle, need to do math
            rest.pendown()
            rest.begin_fill()

            for _ in range(2):
                rest.forward(side_length * 2)
                rest.left(90)
                rest.forward(side_length / 2)
                rest.left(90)
            rest.end_fill()
            rest.penup()
            rest.right(112)  # undo rotation

            rest.forward(3 * side_length / 10)
            rest.right(15)

        # I eyeballed these opposing parameters -- need to do the math
        rest.forward(2 * side_length / 13)
        rest.right(7.5)

wn = Screen()

rest = Turtle()
rest.speed('fastest')
rest.penup()
rest.sety(120)

draw_polygons(20_000)

rest.hideturtle()

wn.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, you just helped me out so much dude. Thank you, a lot. I have managed to figure out the spiral polygons colors problems and solved it already, different from your solution but I am appreciated when you try. But I am still struggling with the flowers' body part and the inside turtle shape, the turtles have different variety of colors as well. Hope hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

On a glance I'd say your indentation is wrong.

```
 for a_color in ["red", "yellow", "blue", "brown", "pink", "green", "black", "orange", "purple"]:
     rest.fillcolor(a_color)
  rest.begin_fill()
```

Here you loop through all colors and then you fill the shape in.
The color will always be purple as this is the last color you set in rest.fillcolor

As one way to solve your problem you could create a list of colors and get the color you need by calling `rest.fillcolor(colors[(i % len(colors)))`.

Comment: However, how can I draw a flower as same as the picture using turtle graphics and function?